# Unique id/code of every deployed application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, publish, uniqueidentifier

I believe every deployed product (application) from VS has a unique id or smth like that, that doesn't change over distribution. What I mean is that I publish an app and give it to a company with 100 employees and the product remains with the same unique ID on every single PC it is installed.

I have come across `GUID` from `Assembly Information` of the program's project, but I am not sure it is that one. So is there anything like such unique id of the product, and if yes - where can I find it AND how can I access it in the code itself. 
I.e.: `string uniqueID = Something.getProductID()` or whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to get GUID,

Fristly, you can get GUID in Assembly Information.

```
//Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Guid id= asm.GetType().GUID;
```

Secondly, It is not taken from the Assembly Information.Stored as a real custom attribute.

```
var attribute = (GuidAttribute)asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute),true)[0].;
var id = attribute.Value;
```

### More info you can see

#### Assembly.GetCustomAttributes Method (Type, Boolean)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88d17d13.aspx

#### Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to acquire it. But the question still remains, whether GUID is the unique identifier of the product, which ID will never change? Or if there is some other ID that plays this role?